# how to get the "inspect elements"(Chrome) code using java?

Tags: java, javascript, html, google-chrome, dom

I want to get text from URL but a swf file is not shown in source code. I can see its link only in inspect element. I've tried Jsoup to get html but it only returns the source code, not the code that is added by the JS. So is there a way to get the code fully like the one in the Inspect elements? or is there a way to get code from Inspect Elements? Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Highlight this and drag it to your book marks and click the book mark on the page you want to inspect:

```
javascript:alert("Inspect Element On");
javascript:document.body.contentEditable = 'true'; 
document.designMode='on'; 
void 0;
javascript:alert(document.documentElement.innerHTML);
```

To turn it off highlight this and drag it to your book marks and click the book mark:

```
javascript:document.body.contentEditable = 'false'; 
document.designMode='on'; 
void 0;j
avascript:alert("Inspect Element Off");
```